# oracle query to get count of added, updated and deleted records based on the date filter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure like below

```
ID OLDID col1 status 
1  0     txt1 A      - inserted record      
2  0     txt1 I      - deleted record
3  0     txt1 I      - updated record
4  3     txt1 I      - updated record
5  4     txt1 I      - updated record
6  5     txt1 I      - deleted record
7  0     txtx I      - updated record
8  7     txt1 A      - updated record
```

I wanted to count the inserted, updated and deleted record in this table, please help me with the oracle query to fetch the count of the records, below are the logic

1. The logic for new record is ID is new ID and old id is 0 and status is A.
2. The updated record's status is I, the id of this record will be inserted into the new record's old id column.
3. the deleted record status with I with old id 0, and the second condition is status is I and ID will not be in OLD id column.

I have tried my best to explain the case, please let me know if any more details are needed. help me with the oracle query.

below query seems to be working, but if no deleted record then **I wanted to have 0 for it but in the below query only returns records which have >0 counts**, can any expert optimize it, please

```
SELECT sub.status, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT CASE 
               WHEN yt.oldid = 0 AND yt.status = 'A' THEN 'Insert'
               WHEN yt.status = 'I' and QID not in (select oldid from FROM your_table where TO_CHAR (record_date,'MM/YYYY')='04/2020' )  THEN 'Delete'
               ELSE 'Update' END AS status
      FROM your_table yt where TO_CHAR (record_date,'MM/YYYY')='04/2020')
GROUP BY sub.status;
```

Neep experts help here, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE..WHEN` and self `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT T.*,
       CASE WHEN T.OLDID = 0 AND T.STATUS = 'A' THEN 'Insert'
            WHEN T.STATUS = 'I' AND T1.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Update'
            WHEN T.STATUS = 'I' AND T.OLDID = 0 AND T1.ID IS NULL THEN 'Delete'
        END AS RECORD_OP
FROM YOUR_TABLE T
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE T1 ON T.ID = T1.OLDID
```